# Assign index to ManyToMany through model

Tags: django

Is it possible to assign an index on objects in a ManyToMany relationship? If I have these models:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    items = models.ManyToManyField(GroupItem, unique=False, through=GroupItem)

class GroupItem(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, unique=False)
    index = models.IntegerField()
```

When I create a group item, I would like to be able to sort that item by index. So if for example I have a group:

```
MyGroup = [MyItem1, MyItem2, MyItem3]
```

But I'd like `MyItem3` to be the first item like so:

```
MyGroup = [MyItem3, MyItem1, MyItem2]
```

How can I do that? Bonus if I can have the index automatically increase as more objects are added to the `Group`

Comment: I'm not getting your question. If you use `index` as the sorting criteria, why can't you do a `order_by` to sort the `GroupItem`? If you want `MyItem3` to be the first, just make it with the smallest index would be OK, right?

Comment: @ShangWang I want to avoid having gaps between the indexes, and have them increase automatically for that specific group it belongs to.

Comment: I think you need to write some logic to do that. I did something similar before but django doesn't have a built in way of doing it. Implement the logic in `pre_save` signal for model `GroupItem` would be a way.

Comment: @ShangWang I'm relatively new to Django, while I still got the basics down and then some I still struggle with things like this. Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably achieve this by using an appropriate default callable:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Track, through="GroupItem")

class Track(models.Model):
    pass

class GroupItem(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    track = models.ForeignKey(Track)
    index = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=get_index)

def get_index():
    latest = GroupItem.objects.aggregate(models.Max("index"))
    latest_index = latest["index__max"]

    # using 0-based indexing, for example
    return latest_index + 1 if latest_index is not None else 0
```

Comment: What is the Track model for?

Comment: @SebastianOlsen: That's from your code: `ManytoManyField(Track)`. The through model needs to have a `ForeignKey` to both sides of the relation, see [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany).

Comment: Oh crap, major mess up on my part. Ignore the Track, that was supposed to say "GroupItem" instead. I'll edit it now.

Comment: @SebastianOlsen: I think you're still confused about M2M fields, you can't have `GroupItem` as both the target and the through model of the M2M.

Comment: Haha oh man. You're right. I know how it works, yes of course there needs to be an actual model that is the many-to-many relation ship.